# How to setup HttpTestingController on async methods that perform multiple async tasks

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Consider the following service method

```js
async save() {
    return this.http.put('/api/foo', this.foo).toPromise();
}
```

usually we can test this like this:

```js
it('should save the foo', async () => {
    const http = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    const save = service.save();
    http.expectOne('/api/foo').flush({ id: 1 });
    expect(await save).toEqual({ id: 1 });
});
```

If we change the implementation of `save()` to await another task before calling http client:

```js
async save() {
    await this.someOtherTask;
    return this.http.put('/api/foo, this.foo).toPromise();
}
```

the test will now fail, because if `save()` returns, the call to http client hasn't been made when the test code reaches the `expectOne` call.

Is there any way to setup `HttpTestingController` upfront without expecting anything? The old AngularJS `$httpBackend` had `when(...).respond(...)` which was much more flexible.

Comment: I think you just need to `await` the `save` call: `const save = await service.save();`

Comment: BTW await,async are just syntax sugar, you can still use the `then`. I'd also say converting an observer to a promise is pretty much a waste of time

Comment: @Liam awaiting the save() call will timeout the test. That's the problem with `HttpTestingController.expectOne`: it's setup and expect in one. What I need is 1st setup, then await call, then expect.

Comment: I'm not following. If you want the result from an async call you have to wait for it. There's also a question as to what exactly your trying to prove with this test?

Comment: @Liam hm, I don't know how to explain it any other way. Of course I want to await it.But if I await it BEFORE I call expectOne, it will wait for the http.put call that won't be resolved (test will timeout). If i await it AFTER expectOne, expectOne will fail, because the code didn't reach the http.put call.

Comment: Sounds like you need to either increase your timeout or not test it. Another options is to abstract out the http calls and mock these, then your not testing the communication. If thats what you want to do then your going to have to wait

Comment: @Liam sorry, but waiting is not an option, because the promise from http.put will never be resolved. I will wait forever. The http call was not setup. The only way (I know) to setup is to call expectOne which immediately checks if the call was actually already done. I would setup a stackblitz if I only knew how to run tests there. If you wanna understand the problem I'd suggest to add the 6 lines of code to some dummy project.